# Django. Conditions in a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a table "Table" and a field "field".
I need to filter the table with the following condition:

```
if (field.isdigit() and len(strip(field)) <= 4):
    do somethimg
```

or

```
if (field.isdigit() and int(field) <= 10000):
    do somethimg
```

How would it look like in a query?

```
Table.objects.filter(condition).update(field="xxx")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can check this with a regex with the [**`__regex`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex):

```
Table.objects.filter(field__regex=r'^\d{,4}$').update(field='xxx')
```

or if leading and trailing spaces are allowed:

```
Table.objects.filter(field__regex=r'^\s*\d{,4}\s*$').update(field='xxx')
```

That being said, if your field contains only numerical data, I strongly advice to make use numerical fields like an [**`IntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#integerfield).

Comment: sorry. forgot to mention. This is a CharField.

Comment: @cegthgtlhj: yes, and normally regular expressions work on a `CharField` :). The point is that if you field only stores numerical data, it is not a good idea to make it a charfield. But if it contains mixed data, you can thus use the `__regex` lookup.

Comment: it is mixed. Thank you. you are the best )